# Python numpy loadtxt fails with date time

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I am trying to use numpy loadtxt to load a csv file into an array. But it seem i can't get the date time correctly loaded.

Below demonstrates what is happening. Did I do something wrong?

```
>>> s = StringIO("05/21/2007,03:27")
>>> np.loadtxt(s, delimiter=",", dtype={'names':('date','time'), 'formats':('datetime64[D]', 'datetime64[m]')})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 796, in loadtxt
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 573, in <lambda>
  return lambda x: int(float(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05/21/2007
```

Comment: but this one works though:
np.datetime64("05/21/2007")
2007-05-21 00:00:00

Comment: please give your code

Comment: @NegativeZero Not for me: `ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "05/21/2007" at position 2`  (numpy version 1.7.0)

Comment: @askewchan I am using 1.6.1 at the moment. I'll upgrade

Comment: You need to provide a converters parameter to deal with datetime types. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: @NegativeZero Hm, from [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html#differences-between-1-6-and-1-7-datetimes): `numpy.datetime64` *New in version 1.7.0.* **Note** *The datetime API is experimental in 1.7.0, and may undergo changes in future versions of NumPy.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also add converters, like:

```
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
...
np.loadtxt(s, delimiter=",", converters={0:strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y'), 1:...}, dtype= ...
```

When numpy sees your dtype format of datetime[64], it prepares to output a column of type numpy.datetime64. numpy.datetim64 is a subclass of numpy.integer, and loadtxt prepares to deal with that column as an integer with the following:

```
def _getconv(dtype):
    typ = dtype.type
    if issubclass(typ, np.bool_):
        return lambda x: bool(int(x))
    if issubclass(typ, np.uint64):
        return np.uint64
    if issubclass(typ, np.int64):
        return np.int64
    if issubclass(typ, np.integer):
        return lambda x: int(float(x))

    ...
```

When it gets to the point of attempting conversion at line 796 in numpyio:

```
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
```

it tries to use`lambda x: int(float(x))` to handle the input. When it does that, it tries to cast your date (05/27/2007) to a float and peters out. The conversion function strpdate2num above will convert the date to a number representation.

Comment: from matplotlib... who knew.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I need to specify the datetime converter.

Answer (score 2):

Trying MichealJCox's solution did not work for me.  My version of numpy (1.8) would not accept a time number as given by `strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')`, it would only accept a date string or datetime object.  Therefore, I used a more complex converter, which converts the time string to a time number and then to a datetime object usable by numpy :

```
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num, num2date
...
convert = lambda x: num2date(strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')(x))
np.loadtxt(s, delimiter=",", converters={0:convert}, dtype= ...
```

This seems like a bulky solution though.