# Convert date from yyyymmddHHMMSS format

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to read two columns (columns 0, 4) of the following ascii file and plot them. One contains the date in yyymmddHHMMSS format which I would like to covert to a date number.

```
# Date          RMS.I   RMS.Q   Cal.I   Cal.Q      
20121220220000 1.45485 1.42051 1.26393 1.29448
20121220230000 1.43377 1.39987 1.26803 1.29874
20121221000000 1.44888 1.41472 1.24759 1.27771
```

I have been using numpy.loadtxt but it reads all columns as float.

```
mydate, myvar = np.loadtxt('infile.txt', comments="#", skiprows=1, usecols=(0,4), unpack=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python numpy loadtxt fails with date time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324440/python-numpy-loadtxt-fails-with-date-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import as a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) as follow:

```
mydate, myvar = np.loadtxt('infile.txt', comments="#", skiprows=1, usecols=(0,4), unpack=True, dtype=[('date', '|S10'), ('floatmio', float)])
```

it will import the date as `str` in `mydate` array. And then you can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library on the single array entries to handle them as follow:

```
import datetime
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H') for x in mydate]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to import as 'str'. 
array([b'2012122022', b'2012122023', b'2012122100', ..., b'2012122112'], 
      dtype='|S10')
In[6]: xd= datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, '%Y%m%d%H')
TypeError: must be str, not numpy.ndarray

Where does the 'b' come from?

Comment: `mydate` is a `numpy.array`. You have to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` on the single entries of the `mydate` array.

Comment: like `datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate[0], '%Y%m%d%H')`

Comment: I already tried that and got TypeError: must be str, not numpy.bytes_
and     `xd=[datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%m%d%y%H%") for x in mydate]` with the same error

Comment: with your code i got a ValueError because the `fmt` is wrong. Try: `xd = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H') for x in mydate]`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the typo - I still get the same error using the correct format.  Eventually, I have traced the problem to using Python 3.4.  If I use 2.7 then the code works fine.  Thanks for your help.