# Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I having a problem to insert a date with loadtxt.

```
dt = np.dtype({'names':['name','height','year'],'formats':['U55','f4','datetime64']})

I = StringIO('Alice,1.75,2000-08-03')


txt = np.loadtxt(I,dtype = dt,delimiter = ',')
txt
```

When I tried to run the code, it returns the following error:`Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units`

I tried to solve as i saw in other question [Python numpy loadtxt fails with date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324440/python-numpy-loadtxt-fails-with-date-time), but i'm failing in import strpdate2num from matplitlib.dates to convert the date.